# Check for duplicates in only two out of three fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm joining 3 tables and use `INSERT` ... `SELECT` to insert the result in `final_table`

```
INSERT INTO final_table (attribute_type, customer_id, product_id, price, price_type, special_price_type, price_value)
    SELECT 1,
           cev.entity_id AS customer_id,
           cpe.entity_id AS product_id,
           it.price,
           1,
           1,
           it.price
    FROM catalog_product_entity cpe JOIN
         import_tmp it
         ON cpe.sku = it.sku JOIN
         customer_entity_varchar cev
         ON cev.value IN (it.customer, it.grp)
    WHERE cev.attribute_id IN (139, 140)
```

There might be duplicates **only** on these two fields:

```
cev.entity_id AS customer_id,
cpe.entity_id AS product_id
```

Is it possible to use `DISTINCT` to check for duplicates on only two out of three fields? Or is there any other way to accomplish this? Thank you

EDIT:
Sample data:

```
customer_id - product_id - price
ABC - 123 - 100
CDE - 345 - 500
ABC - 123 - 400
```

Desired result:

```
customer_id - product_id - price
ABC - 123 - 100
CDE - 345 - 500
```

So basically remove the duplicate of `ABC - 123` pair.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: In Postgres, you can use DISTINCT ON to accomplish this. In MySQL, you can use row number or group by on specific fields

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added sample and desired result. Thanks

Comment: @hardy123480 
Suppose that your first table is `customer_product`.

You can write a query like this:

```select customer_id, product_id, min(price) from customer_product group by customer_id, product_id```

Comment: @AnhDucNg Thank you. I think this is what I need.I will do some more tests, though. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your sample data, you simply want aggregation:

```
select customer_id, product_id, min(price)
from t
group by customer_id, product_id;
```

Comment: I think sum is incorrect based on his sample data. It should be min instead